# image url of some kind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have 2 lines like this:

```
<img height="100" width="100" src="../uploadimages/18-2-2013-23-33-01-Lighthouse.jpg">

<asp:Image id="img_prev" name="img_prev" src="" Height="80" Width="100" runat="server" />
img_prev.ImageUrl = "../uploadimages/18-2-2013-23-33-01-Lighthouse.jpg"
```

I try to show image in 2 html image and .net image, in html code its shows goods, but in .net image it can not show to image.

Comment: Please check what is rendered in the html page - and there you can see why your image is not loaded. Also you do not need to place the `name` as attribute on the asp:image, and I hope that the `img_prev.ImageUrl` exist on code behind.

Comment: What in the world does this have to do with C#?

Comment: No, I didn't forget. That was my first edit. Was just curious where the c# code was.

Answer (score 2):

try with this

```
<asp:Image id="Img1" runat="server" Height="80" Width="100" ImageUrl="../uploadimages/18-2-2013-23-33-01-Lighthouse.jpg" />
```

or remove `src=""`

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you are trying to use the asp image control?  Typically, you would only want to use that if you have a need to access the control on the server side.

try this.

```
img_prev.ImageUrl = "~/folder/filename";
```